# An issue with a "Screen lock key" Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'd like to create a Tampermonkey script that places a key-shaped lock on the left side of the browser screen. Only by clicking on this key can other areas of the screen be interacted with. Otherwise, interaction is limited to the key itself. Essentially, the key acts as a screen lock, serving as a tool to prevent accidental taps.

I'm currently facing a challenging situation.
When this script locks the page, even the key is locked. Is it possible to modify it so that when the page is locked, only the interface other than the key is locked?

Here is my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Screen Lock Key
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Locks the screen until a key is clicked.
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Create the key-shaped lock element
    const lockButton = document.createElement('div');
    lockButton.id = 'lockButton';
    lockButton.style.position = 'fixed';
    lockButton.style.left = '0';
    lockButton.style.top = '50%';
    lockButton.style.transform = 'translateY(-50%)';
    lockButton.style.width = '20px';
    lockButton.style.height = '20px';
    lockButton.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    lockButton.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    lockButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    lockButton.style.zIndex = '9999';
    document.body.appendChild(lockButton);

    let isLocked = false;

    // Lock Screen Button Click Event
    lockButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        if (isLocked) {
            isLocked = false;
            lockButton.style.backgroundColor = 'gray'; // Unlocked state.
            document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; // Enable click events for the page.
        } else {
            isLocked = true;
            lockButton.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // Locked State
            document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Disable click events for the entire page.
        }
    });
})();
```

Thank you very much for considering my request. Your assistance would not only help me overcome this obstacle but also contribute to my growth as a developer. I look forward to your positive response.

I hope to achieve the functionality where the "key" can toggle between "unlocking" and "locking" states. In the locked state, the key would effectively disable any interactions with the entire browser interface, rendering everything unclickable. When in the unlocked state, normal interactions on web pages should resume. Furthermore, during the locked state, video playback within the browser should remain unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this issue!

The issue is that when I apply the pointerEvents = 'none' to the body, it also applies to the child elements, including "key".

A simple way to solve this is to apply pointerEvents = 'auto' to the key after setting pointerEvents = 'none' for the body.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Screen Lock Key
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Locks the screen until a key is clicked.
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Create the key-shaped lock element
    const lockButton = document.createElement('div');
    lockButton.id = 'lockButton';
    lockButton.style.position = 'fixed';
    lockButton.style.left = '0';
    lockButton.style.top = '50%';
    lockButton.style.transform = 'translateY(-50%)';
    lockButton.style.width = '20px';
    lockButton.style.height = '20px';
    lockButton.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    lockButton.style.borderRadius = '50%';
    lockButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    lockButton.style.zIndex = '9999';
    document.body.appendChild(lockButton);

    let isLocked = false;

    // Lock Screen Button Click Event
    lockButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        if (isLocked) {
            isLocked = false;
            lockButton.style.backgroundColor = 'gray'; // Unlocked state.
            document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; // Enable click events for the page.
        } else {
            isLocked = true;
            lockButton.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // Locked State
            document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Disable click events for the entire page.
            lockButton.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; // Enable click events for the key.
        }
    });
})();
```

But also note that this method has limitations. For example, if a webpage has some elements with a higher z-index than the key, they may overlap key and make it unclickable.